# iBeacon battery level indication using esp32 bleclient

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I was tring to get the battery level and RSSI value along with distance in mtr of iBeacon acting as server and ESP32 acting as aclient which can collect data from surrounding iBeacons.

I tried doing like finding the rssi values for surrounding ble devices. But i also want to get the battery level of the perticular beacon im intrested in.

Comment: Standard iBeacon advertisement does not include battery level.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no standard way of encoding a battery level in iBeacon, you have a couple of options if you can control your advertised beacon format:

1. Use the iBeacon major or minor field to send the battery level.  (This is I’ll only work if you control the software for the transmitter). If encoded in the minor field here is how you might parse that on the ESP32:

```
static int parse_battery_level_from_ibeacon_minor(int length, uint8_t *adv_buffer) {
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (i < length-4) {
      if (adv_buffer[i] == 0x4c &&
          adv_buffer[i+1] == 0x00 &&
          adv_buffer[i+2] == 0x02 &&
          adv_buffer[i+3] == 0x15) {
            return buffer[i+23]; // LSB of minor
          }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

2. Instead of the iBeacon format, use the similar [AltBeacon format](https://github.com/AltBeacon/spec) which has an extra manufacturer reserved data byte in the transmission commonly used to encode the battery level.  Some off the shelf beacons like [RadBeacon](https://shop.flybuy.com/products/radbeacon-01-dot) support this battery encoding in this field:

```
static int parse_battery_level_from_altbeacon_data(int length, uint8_t *adv_buffer) {
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (i < length-4) {
      if (adv_buffer[i] == 0x18 &&
          adv_buffer[i+1] == 0x01 &&
          adv_buffer[i+2] == 0xbe &&
          adv_buffer[i+3] == 0xac) {
            return buffer[i+24]; // reserved data field
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```